# Image Embedding

Tags: php, html, css

I am  currently having issues inserting an image to this template.

Original Code:

```
$subject = "$sitename";
$body = "<p >Dear $first_name</p> <p>We are pleased to inform you that your account has been created </p>  <center>Account Information</center> <p> Username - $username </p> <p> Status - $status </p>";
```

I want to add logo, and I tried:

```
$subject = "$sitename";        
$body = "<img src='../uploads/<?php echo $site_logo; ?>' <p>Dear $first_name</p> <p>We are pleased to inform you that your account has been created </p>  <center>Account Information</center> <p> Username - $username </p> <p> Status - $status</p> ";
```

I want the site logo to appear first but the image is not appearing when I send email. If I add double quotation i.e "" in after the src, it returns error.

Please I'll appreciate if someone can help. Thanks!!

Comment: Putting a php block and echo inside another php string makes zero sense and won't work. Just concatenate the $site_logo variable into the string, or include it within the string directly so it gets interpolated. You can already see how this is done from your original code (e.g. with the $first_name variable)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I initially tried $site_logo but it only showed the image name i.e logo.jpg in the email template instead of the actual image. Any further suggestions?

Comment: If this is intended for an email then you'll need to supply the full URL of the image to the template, not just the filename. An email client can't work on just a relative URL, (because there is no context of the current domain, unlike when you are loading a page in a browser)

Comment: Thank you... I right clicked on the logo and selected 'copy image address' and replaced it with where I have $site_logo.. so it was like this src='https://my website.com/logo.png'..... and it worked fine